# HDFS Short circuit reads

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

According to the [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ShortCircuitLocalReads.html), short circuit reads are faster as they doesn't go through the data node. If this is the case then

1. Why isn't this enabled by default?
2. In which scenarios do we need short circuit reading?

Comment: Good question. I don't know why it's not enabled by default. I've never encountered a situation where short circuit reads was a bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/08/how-improved-short-circuit-local-reads-bring-better-performance-and-security-to-hadoop/

Summary of article:

One major downside to the original implementation is that it screwed with security implications. It had to give clients direct read access to the data files. I guess this was bad for kerberos enabled hdfs.

The new implementation passes a file descriptor instead, which supposedly is more secure and faster.

I guess there were some downsides to the old method. I don't see what the downsides to the new method are. I couldn't find a definitive answer in which version of Hadoop the new method appeared.